# How to connect null values with dotted lines in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to connect null values with dotted lines in the chart.
Below is the url to JS fiddle where my code resides -

```
data:  [
        [Date.UTC(2016, 1, 1),null], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 2, 1),null], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 3, 1),500], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 4, 1),600], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 5, 1),null], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 6, 1),700], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 1),null], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 8, 1),null], 
        [Date.UTC(2016, 9, 1),null],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 10, 1),null],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 1),null], 
        [Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1),500]
        ],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/ue0wb8w0/

Comment: You would need to create another series with your null points connected using a different `dashstyle`.

Comment: @wergeld I am new to highcharts thing. Could you please post a fiddle with an example which uses data that is mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [series.zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones) to define which part of the graph will be dashed.

Based on your data, the algorithm for building the zones array could be sth like this (feel free to adjust it the way you want):

```
function buildZones(data) {
  var zones = [],
      i = -1, len = data.length, current, previous, dashStyle, value;

  while (data[++i] === null);
  zones.push({
    value: i
  });

  while (++i < len) {
    previous = data[i - 1];
    current = data[i];
    dashStyle = '';

    if (previous !== null && current === null) {
      dashStyle = 'solid';
      value = i - 1;
    } else if (previous === null && current !== null) {
      dashStyle = 'dot';
      value = i;
    }

    if (dashStyle) {
      zones.push({
        dashStyle: dashStyle,
        value: value
      });
    }
  }

  return zones;
}
```

Series config:

```
series: [{
  zones: buildZones(data),
  zoneAxis: 'x',
  data: data,
  connectNulls: true
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/asf52ft8/

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems very promising, +1 for that. Just to add, x-axis in my chart has date values' labels. I tried to use your solution in my chart. Finding difficulty in doing so. It's area chart. I have updated the fiddle.
    http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/ue0wb8w0/

Comment: I have updated the fiddle in my question. Also, the data would come dynamically. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In this case you need to treat zones' value as data's x attribute (date) instead of the counter - http://jsfiddle.net/ue0wb8w0/1/ If you want to change the area color/pattern, you need to set zones.fillColor http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones.fillColor

Comment: The problem statement is - for dashStyle = dot I don't want to fill color. It should be dotted line in this case (just like line chart as shown in image above). And for dashStyle = solid it should show the color as being shown in your fiddle.

Comment: fillColor defines area's color, dashStyle defines upper line's style - http://jsfiddle.net/ue0wb8w0/3/

Comment: Your code worked well except one scenario where all values are null. I applied a workaround for all null case and it worked fine. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I Think Its Fine For You.. This Graph Suitable For Irregular Intervals

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth at Kerala, India'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
            month: '%b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Winter 2017',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2017,01,01), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,04,01), 6],
            [Date.UTC(2017,05,01), 3],
            [Date.UTC(2017,06,01), 7],
            [Date.UTC(2017,07,01), 5],
            [Date.UTC(2017,12,01), 6],
        ]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Where are the null values used in your series data? Please go through the question again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this One too

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Winter 2012-2013',
        // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
        // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
        // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.25],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 27), 0.2],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 2), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 26), 0.28],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 29), 0.47],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 11), 0.79],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 26), 0.72],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 3), 1.02],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 11), 1.12],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 25), 1.2],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 11), 1.18],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 11), 1.19],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 1), 1.85],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 5), 2.22],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 19), 1.15],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 3), 0]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Winter 2013-2014',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 29), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.4],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 1), 0.25],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 1), 1.66],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 10), 1.8],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 19), 1.76],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 25), 2.62],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19), 2.41],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 30), 2.05],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 14), 1.7],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 24), 1.1],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 10), 0]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Winter 2014-2015',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 6), 0.25],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 20), 1.41],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.64],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 4), 1.6],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 17), 2.55],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 24), 2.62],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 4), 2.5],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 14), 2.42],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 6), 2.74],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 14), 2.62],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 24), 2.6],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 2), 2.81],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 12), 2.63],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 28), 2.77],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 5), 2.68],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 10), 2.56],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 15), 2.39],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 20), 2.3],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 5), 2],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 10), 1.85],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 15), 1.49],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 23), 1.08]
        ]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see null values in your series' data. Please go through the question.